# Is there a way to be able to exclude the bottom right corner of a div from this function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, performance

below here is some javascript code to be able to drag elements around the page. How would I be able to also resize the div without moving it around. For example exclude 5px from the bottom right of the div or something like that.

```
dragElement(document.querySelector(".dragTime"));
dragElement(document.querySelector("#full-date"));
dragElement(document.querySelector("#stocks"));
   function dragElement(ele) {
      var pos1 = 0,
      pos2 = 0,
      pos3 = 0,
      pos4 = 0;
      if (document.querySelector(ele.id + "header")) {
         document.getElementById(
            ele.id + "header"
         ).onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }
      else {
         ele.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }
      function dragMouseDown(e) {
         e = e || window.event;
         e.preventDefault();
         pos3 = e.clientX;
         pos4 = e.clientY;
         document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
         document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      }
      function elementDrag(e) {
         e = e || window.event;
         e.preventDefault();
         pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX ;
         pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY ;
         pos3 = e.clientX;
         pos4 = e.clientY;
         ele.style.top = ele.offsetTop - pos2 + "px";
         ele.style.left = ele.offsetLeft - pos1 + "px";
      }
      function closeDragElement() {
         document.onmouseup = null;
         document.onmousemove = null;
      }
   }
```

Any help would be great please and thanks

Comment: yeah, put something in there with opacity:0 and cancel the event when clicking on it

Comment: How would I be able to do this. Sorry I am a begginer to all of this.